# AP scan leads to no results

Tags: wifi

I just get my new **Raspberrry Pi 2** and installed both *raspbian* and *archlinux arm*. And both gave me the `No scan results` when I run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`. I tried with both my wifi dongle, the tl-WN725N and my belkin n150...

I thought that it could be the power supply that could be not powerfull enough because I was using a battery pack. But now that I use a normal 5V/2A power supply, I still get the same result.

I  did not attempt to continue my wifi setup thinking it will lead to nothing good with that start...

And I am a little lost at why I got such a 'No results' output.

Comment: Is your AP hidden ?

Comment: no. There is no results at all.